# Нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки открывалось поверх основного окна окно с регистрацией или входом

Tags: angular

Я в html файле  написал такое сверху страницы

```
<nav class="my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
        <button #button class="btn btn-primary">Login in</button>
    </nav>
    <button #button class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
```

Но они не  реагируют и не переходят  никуда.

я пробывал и (click) додавать . всеравно не реагирует.Как повесить на нее клик?

У меня есть файлы

```
registration.ts
registration.html
registration.css
```

и для входа

```
signup.ts
signup.html
signup.css
```

И я  не  знаю как сделать в html чтобы оно открывалося  повверх основного окна... Я не нашел в инете ничего чтобы мне помогло...
Нужна ваша помощь

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/07/12/angular-8-custom-modal-window-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите material dialog  там есть [примеры](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

Comment: А где связь между bootstrap и material?

Comment: а зачем тебе свзязь между бутстрапом?

Comment: а по классам не видно что он использует bootstrap? :)

Comment: а кто запрещает использовать material  в bootstrap?

Comment: подключать бандл размером 1 мегабайт из-за модалки? Довольно интересное решение. > `а кто запрещает использовать material в bootstrap?` - вопрос тоже интересный) учитывая тот фактор, что в bootstrap уже есть этот функционал

Comment: проверьте подключили ли вы скрипты js  из бутстрапа

Comment: на то пошло можно и без бутстрапа